# How to convert a list of dictionaries inside a tuple into tabular data/ pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, tuples

I currently have a list of tuples with two elements, a string and dictionary of three key-value pairs.

```
list1 = [("string1", {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}), 
         ("string2", {"a": 11, "b": 21, "c": 31}), ...]
```

This is a mess. I would like to put this is DataFrame format.The intended format should be

```
strings    a    b    c
string1    1    2    3
string2    11   21   31
```

How does put extract this into a DataFrame like format? For the first elements in the tuples, I would suspect we would unpack the strings as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
for i in list1:
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df["strings"] = pd.DataFrame([list1[i][0]]) # create the `strings` column
    # place the 2nd element of the tuple in a DataFrame, and then merge with `df`
    df = df.merge(df, pd.DataFrame(list1[0][i]))
```

This of course doesn't work.

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Want would be the best way to munge the original data structure into tabular format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
list1 = [("string1", {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}), 
         ("string2", {"a": 11, "b": 21, "c": 31})]

df = pd.DataFrame([row[1] for row in list1]) # create df from list of dicts
df["strings"] = [row[0] for row in list1] # add the string column
```

and if needed you can add:

```
df.set_index("strings", inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, you can convert the list to a dictionary and then use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict`:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(list1), orient="index").rename_axis("strings").reset_index()

#    strings     b   a   c
#0   string1     2   1   3
#1   string2    21  11  31
```